# Create an array of objects ordered based on the attribute of a child class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting

I have class `Job`:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stops
end
```

`Stop` class has an attribute, `datetime :arrival time`

What is a concise way to get an array of all jobs, ordered by the earliest arrival time on associated stops?

e.g.

If job_1 has two stops, one with arrival time of 4pm and one with arrival time of 5pm.

And job_2 has two stops, one with arrival time of 3pm and one with arrival time of 6pm.

i need the `array: [job_2, job_1]`

I'm able to achieve this, but in a a cumbersome way, which involves looping and temporarily storing values.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Stop.all.order_by(arrival_time: :asc).select(:job).distinct
```

It will take all stops ordered by arrival time,then select only unique jobs.
Make sure the Stop model has a belongs_to :job.

Comment: Thanks, this is great. I'll actually use the solution below as I can apply the sort to any subset of jobs, but you get the bacon for getting in first :)

Comment: Your solution doesn't work in my playground, I post my working version to complete your answer : `Stop.all.order(arrival_time: :asc).select(:job_id).distinct`. And doesn't return an array of jobs like the op asked, but an array of stops. Anyway the response is good.

Comment: I got an error ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "job" does not exist

Comment: and I'm not sure is it `order_by` or just `order`?

Answer (score 3):

This is a good question! Francesco's answer should you to where youre going but if you prefer to utilize joins over subseries you have some other options as well.

```
Job.includes(:stops).order('stops.arrival_time ASC')
```

Swap `includes` with `joins` if you want to omit jobs that do not have any stops